# What object (key-value) can I use for actionscript's URLRequest/Loader classes?

Tags: actionscript, key, urlloader, urlrequest

I am trying to get my Actionscript program to turn in a key-value (more specifically: a key, value1, value2) object into a server.  I am doing the html request properly, but I'm not sure what kind of object to send;  can anyone help?

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I understand correctly you want to post an object to the server, which has 1 key and multiple values. The latter is not supported by a HTTP_POST/GET call, you could however use something as AMF to send a VO from Flash over to a server and decode the AMF object on the server. Not sure whether or not that is where you are looking for, or you just want to post 2 values to a server.

Posting 2 values to a server is simple, but it requires two keys.

```
public function URLVariablesExample() {
        var url:String = "http://www.domain.com/script.php";
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.keyOne = new Date().getTime();
        variables.keyTwo = "Something";
        request.data = variables;
        navigateToURL(request);
}
```